# Using get method inside a service

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following service:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AdminBundle\Service;

class Paginator
{

    private $data;

    private $offset;

    private $get_parameters;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // just an empty constructor here
    }

    public function init($data, $offset, $get_parameters)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->offset = $offset;
        $this->get_parameters = $get_parameters;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaginator()
    {
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        // ...
    }

} // End Paginator
```

It doesn't work however - get function is undefined in getPaginator() method. Is there a way to solve this issue, and call get method from service class?

Comment: Are you trying to `extend` another class? You can't call functions that aren't defined and there's no base set of functions for an object in PHP without inheritance or traits.

Comment: I think I just want to call a 'knp_paginator' service here, is there another way to do this than get() method like in my post?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject `knp_paginator` service to the `Paginator` service inside the service definition.

Please read the [Service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) cookbook page in Symfony documentation, especially *[Referencing (Injecting) Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services)* section.